# how to create a dataframe form a lists within a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

is there a chance to get a dataframe from a list that contains further lists?
my data looks like this:

```
> head(list,3)
[[1]]

           7           36           37           41           42           47           48           49           58 
0.0162201303 0.0072411296 0.0144822592 0.0175235337 0.0001448226 0.3943519189 0.0043446778 0.0013034033 0.0097031137 
          61           87          132          134          143          144          145          146          147 
0.0041998552 0.0005792904 0.0008689356 0.0002896452 0.1963794352 0.0002896452 0.0085445329 0.0108616944 0.0062273715 
         148          149          150          151          152          153          163          170          171 
0.0224475018 0.0043446778 0.0273714699 0.0004344678 0.0004344678 0.0069514844 0.0002896452 0.0083997104 0.0031860970 
         172          173          174          175          176          177          179 
0.0037653874 0.1863866763 0.0169442433 0.0047791455 0.0186821144 0.0002896452 0.0017378711 

[[2]]

           7           36           37           47           48           49           58           61           87 
3.493614e-02 6.260957e-05 6.260957e-05 2.948911e-02 8.139244e-04 1.001753e-03 1.252191e-04 1.001753e-03 6.260957e-05 
          88           89           91           92           93           94           95           96           97 
1.252191e-04 6.260957e-05 7.951415e-03 5.634861e-03 1.296018e-02 2.504383e-04 5.071375e-03 5.256699e-01 4.695718e-03 
          99          109          110          134          143          144          145          146          147 
7.012271e-03 6.448785e-03 1.252191e-04 3.130478e-04 3.156148e-01 6.260957e-05 2.880040e-03 3.130478e-03 9.015778e-03 
         148          149          150          151          152          153 
5.384423e-03 1.001753e-02 3.881793e-03 1.878287e-04 6.260957e-05 5.885299e-03 

[[3]]

          7          36          37          38          41          42          47          49          58          61 
0.009215442 0.002241594 0.004234122 0.000747198 0.007721046 0.000249066 0.129514321 0.002490660 0.002988792 0.000747198 
         62          91          92          93          94          95          96          97          99         109 
0.000996264 0.018929016 0.001494396 0.041344956 0.000498132 0.008966376 0.709589041 0.002241594 0.053300125 0.001494396 
        110         132         134 
0.000249066 0.000249066 0.000498132
```

I would like to have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID Var1    Var 2 Var 3
7  0.016 0.0035   0.009
36 0.007 0.0000   0.002
37 0.014 0.0000   0.004
38 NA      NA     0.000
41 0.0175  NA     0.007
42 0.00014 NA     0.000
47 0.39    NA     0.13
...
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `melt/dcast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(lapply(l1, function(x) as.data.frame.list(x))),
                          variable~paste0('Var',L1), value.var='value')
#     variable Var1 Var2 Var3
#1        X7    3   NA    8
#2        X9    2   NA   10
#3        X1    6    9   NA
#4        X5    9    2    9
#5        X2    3   NA   NA
#6        X3    5    8    5
#7        X6    2    7   10
#8       X10   NA   10    5
#9        X4   NA    2    4
#10       X8   NA   NA   10
```

Or a variation suggested by @Ananda Mahto

```
 dcast(melt(lapply(l1, as.matrix)), Var1 ~ L1, value.var = "value")
```

Or you could use `rbindlist` which will give a `wider` dataset

```
 library(data.table)
 rbindlist(lapply(l1, function(x) as.data.frame.list(x)), fill=TRUE)
# X7 X9 X1 X5 X2 X3 X6 X10 X4 X8
#1:  3  2  6  9  3  5  2  NA NA NA
#2: NA NA  9  2 NA  8  7  10  2 NA
#3:  8 10 NA  9 NA  5 10   5  4 10
```

#### data

```
set.seed(49)
l1 <- lapply(1:3 ,function(i) {x1 <- sample(1:10,sample(5:10),replace=TRUE)
         names(x1) <- sample(1:10, length(x1),replace=FALSE)
             x1})
```

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks, yes, it needs to be transposed.  I can remove it.